# No se guardan los datos en el SQL y Java

Tags: java, sql

**Buenas estoy tratando de guardar datos en una base de datos, me sale se guardaron correctamente los datos sin embargo no aparecen en el SQL, estoy trabajando con MVC y CRUD no se que puede estar mal espero que puedan ayudarme**

```
public void Create(Personal per) {
    try{
        st = conexion.createStatement();
        rs = st.executeQuery("insert into DPersonal ("+per.getCodigo()+",'"+per.getDNI()+",'"+per.getNombre()+",'"
                +per.getApellido()+",'"+per.getEdad()+per.getSexo()+",'"+per.getDireccion()+",'"
                +per.getCelular()+",'"+per.getCorreo()+per.getFoto()+",') values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?");
    } catch (Exception ex){
        Mensajes.MD("Datos registrados correctamente");
    }
}


   @Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    if (ae.getSource() == vista.btnGuardar) {
        //lectura de datos
        int cod = Integer.parseInt(vista.txtCodigoP.getText());
        String dni = vista.txtDNIP.getText();
        String nom = vista.txtNombreP.getText();
        String ape = vista.txtApellidosP.getText();
        int ed = Integer.parseInt(vista.txtEdadP.getText());
        String s = vista.cboSexoP.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String direc = vista.txtDireccionP.getText();
        int cl = Integer.parseInt(vista.txtCelularP.getText());
        String cor = vista.txtCorreoP.getText();
        Icon f = vista.jlblFoto.getIcon();
        //creamos el objeto
        Personal per = new Personal(cod, dni, nom, ape, ed, s, direc, cl, cor, f);
        //lo insertamos en la BD
        CRUDpersonal cp = new CRUDpersonal();
        cp.Create(per);
    }
```

Comment: Una excepción se captura (catch) después de que tu código la lance, y el código lanza una excepción **cuando ha ocurrido un error**. Muestra el tipo y contenido de la excepción para saber más.

Comment: Te manda que se guardo correctamente por que tienes una excepción y en el catch mandas ese mensaje, en realidad no esta guardando nada, y el insert deberia ir de el tipo `insert into DPersonal (campo1, campo2, campo3) values('valor1', 'valor2)`, y tu estas enviando un `insert into DPersonal(valor1, valor2,valor3)`